# Найти самую длинную строку, которая является подстрокой всех слов

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Требуется написать программу, которая принимает несколько слов, и нам нужно найти то, которое чаще всего повторяется. Подскажите, есть ли какие-нибудь функции?  А то понятия не имею как это написать

Пример ввода:
Sample Samplin SamplingsFun Saplingdsajisfasfijoi

Пример вывода:
Sampl

Comment: Задача не поставлена нормально. Кроме того, нужно показать свои размышления и попытки

Comment: Ваши-то идеи где?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вашему вопросу ваш преподаватель не ждет от вас использование каких-либо "готовых функций". Это классическая задача на алгоритмы. Она сводится к нахождению общей подстроки попарно между всеми имеющимися строками.
Алгоритм примерно такой:

1. Берете первые 2 слова (обозначим их длины x1 и x2) и строите матрицу (двумерный массив) размером x1+1 на x2+1
2. Заполняете первый столбец матрицы нулями
3. Заполняете первую строку матрицы нулями
4. Заполняете клетки на пересечении разных букв нулями
5. Заполняете клетки на пересечении одинаковых букв значением равным значению на пересечении двух предыдущих индексов плюс 1 (то есть если сейчас вы смотрите индексы 5 и 7 и в заголовках этих двух индексов одинаковые буквы, то вы берете значение из клетки 4 и 6 и прибавляете к нему 1 и результат записываете в клетку с индексом 5 и 7)

Все пункты с 2 по 5 само собой делаются за один раз в двух вложенных циклах. После чего ваша таблица для первой пары слов готова.

6. Находите в полученной матрице самое большое число...
7. ...и двигаясь по диагонали от него ( каждый раз уменьшая оба индекса на единицу переписываете посимвольно любой из заголовков матрицы - это и есть повторяющиеся символы в этой паре строк)

В итоге после сравнения первых двух слов у вас есть общая строка для этой пары, третью строку можно уже сравнивать с полученной подстрокой и тем самым уточнить полученный результат и так далее. Но нужно учитывать, что подстрок может оказаться несколько и тогда лучше отслеживать все варианты - лишние в ходе проверок сами должны отсеяться.

P.S.: Задача на столько типовая, что по ней и ей подобным есть целый ворох статей в вики, главное правильно сформулировать [вопрос](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0)!